# Text absolute positioning within styled bar at 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with a header bar that is 100% width and footer that is 100% width, but the content is centered and only say 800px wide.

I am attempting to make text float justified to the content area upon window stretch, but can't figure the best way to to this.

[**EXAMPLE**](http://www.toddmarx.com/bar_example.gif)

I've tried absolute positioning and relative positioning within the header div but when the window stretches, I either get the text 1 staying in the same spot, or it completely left justifies within the text 1 bar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post relevant code please

Comment: @user3777882: A bit clear please

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KAtCb)

You can remove `width: 100%` as its block element it will take full width.

And add one more div inside header and footer with `width: 800px` and `margin: 0 auto`
to center the inner content.

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<header> <div class="cnt">Header Text</div> </header>

    <div class="content">
        Div content......
    </div>

<footer><div class="cnt">Footer Text</div> </footer>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{

    height:100%;
}
   header,footer{

    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.cnt,
  .content{
    width:800px;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting:

HTML:

```
   <div class="container">

    <header> <div class="content">Header Text</div> </header>

    <div class="content">
        Container Text
    </div>

<footer> Footer Text </footer>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
      .container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
header,footer{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}

.content{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid blue;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t47cp/4/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

    <header> <div class="content">Header Text</div> </header>

    <div class="content">
        Container Text
    </div>

    <footer> <div class="content"> Footer Text</div> </footer>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
header,footer{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}

.content{
    width:800px;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid blue;
    text-align:justify;
}
```